# Dropdown menu - Filter table with select option

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like when the user clicked in the option of the dropdown menu the table filter the records with this option.

At moment when I filter this records the thead of the table disappear, this is because I use the tag `<tr>` to filter it.

My code:

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left  btn-group" style="padding-right: 10px;">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">EDICIÓ
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" id="drEdicion">
        <li><a href=#>TOT</a></li>
  <?php 
    $result = dbQuery($conn, "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_edicion");
    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
        <li><a href=#><?php echo $row[2]; ?></a></li>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>


<script>

$('#drEdicion li').click(function(){

    var ed = $(this).text();

    $('#titEdicion').text('EDICIÓ: ' + ed);
    $("tr[data-ediction!='"+ed+"']").hide();
    $("tr[data-ediction='"+ed+"']").show(); 

});

</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<thead class='thead-inverse'>
  <tr>  
    <th data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>
    <th data-field='estado' data-switchable='false'></th>
    <th data-field='edicion' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>EDICIÓ</th>
```

Select the option:

[image]

Choose option:

[image]

The head of the table disappears:

[image]

I do not know if there is a better option or not.

Comment: I would use <thead> for the headers instead of <tr> - so they won't get hidden.

Comment: The code of the head of the table combine <thead> and <tr>. I have updated with the html code of the table.

Comment: Cool! so I would make sure <thead> is being used for headers and <tbody> for content rows :) so you can target accordingly.

Comment: How do it to select tbody tr with jquery?

Comment: $("tbody tr[data-ediction!='"+ed+"']").hide();